# Is there any way to mask out surface and leave reflection/shadow only?

Tags: compositing-nodes, shadowcatcher, cryptomatte

I'm trying to create a composite image with bottles on a table and I need to have shadow/refraction/gloss of the bottle to be separate from the bottle itself. I tried Shadow Catcher pass, but it creates something messy and wrong, that doesn't look right when used with Multiply in Photoshop. Is there any way to mask out table surface in this case and just keep whatever shadow/gloss the bottle produces? Or create a pass that would have all of these combined or at least separate layers I could combine in PS?

[image]

Comment: If you mean that you want layers that separate out the rendered static part of the background from the object area that includes a rendered shadow (animation purposes?).... you could try using a Mask modifier on the non-shadow static surface and then reverse the mask for rendering that includes the shadow.  Define a vertex group that includes the shadow area for the Mask.

Comment: Not exactly, I want the pass to have just shadow/reflection only, I don't need table surface itself. Usually 3D software has "matte reflection" option, but I don't think Blender has anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for objects, when Cycles is the render engine being used, to use them as “shadow catchers.“ They will not be shown in the render except in reflections on other objects, and shadows will cast onto them. This option is in the Visibility panel in the Object tab in the Properties editor, with the object selected.

Comment: I'm looking to have a reflection catcher though, not just a shadow.